# 2 gang light switch has 4 brown wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

Can anyone help here with trying to replace a light switch? The old one has 4 cables entering the backbox with all blue and earths joined together, but the new switch requires a neutral and which brown wire(s) to use?
thanks in advance

Old switch
[image]

New switch
[image]

Comment: Based on the wire colors, I assume you're in the UK/EU.  Can you provide a better pic showing where the wires actually connect?  All we can see is a bunch of wires terminating somewhere behind what looks to be some kind of Wago (or similar) connector.

Comment: @Huesmann we're looking at the back of the switches. The wires are going into the switches' integrated screw terminals.

Comment: I don’t see an NRTL listing printed on that switch. Is there one? If not, good luck…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't state in which part of the world you are located, I am going to assume that the brown wires are used for live/hot and the blue for neutral.

First off, you stated "all blue and earths joined together". I hope that you meant that all blue wires are joined together and the earth wires are joined together, but the blues are not joined with the earths.
If the blue and earth wires are joined in one big join, you should rectify that before someone gets killed.

Then, to connect your new switch, add a short piece of blue wire to the join of the blues (a pigtail) and connect that to the "N in" terminal of your switch.

The brown wire going to the top of the old switch(es) goes to the "L in" terminal of the new switch.

The single brown wire in the bottom left of the old switch goes to one of the "Out" terminals of the new switch.

The two brown wires in the bottom right of the old switch should go into a join with a pigtail of brown wire. That pigtail then goes into the other "Out" terminal of the new switch.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for responding.  ps. I am in the UK